# Web scraping for SpaceX jobs USING RSTUDIO

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Use this link to answer the following questions. "https://www.spacex.com/careers/?department="

1. Create a dataframe of all jobs at SpaceX. Show the first 10 in a table. (Use `knitr::kable()` to create a table)
2. Create another dataframe that shows how many jobs are in each state. (If there are multiple locations choose the first one). Show the dataframe in a table.

Comment: You can try packages `rvest` `RSelenium`. Provide proper link and mention data to extracted.

Comment: All of the provided information is in the question: I need to grab all jobs and then count the number jobs by state.

Answer (score 0):

Try `RSelenium` package,

```
#Launch server 
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))

remDr <- driver[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.spacex.com/careers/?department=")
button_element <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="jobs-list"]/table')
#get the table
df = button_element$getElementText()

#Converting the text to table 
library(vroom)
df= vroom(df[[1]])
# A tibble: 930 x 5
   JOB         TITLE       LOCATION EMPLOYMENT   TYPE                                                                              
   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    <chr>        <chr>                                                                             
 1 Application Software    Engineer Hawthorne,   CA, United States Full-Time                                                       
 2 Application Software    Engineer Brownsville, TX, United States Full-Time                                                       
 3 Application Software    Engineer (Developer   Tools) Hawthorne, CA, United States Full-Time                                     
 4 Application Software    Engineer II           Hawthorne, CA, United States Full-Time
```